# How can I disable GHCUp upgrade attempts in VS Code's Haskell extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, haskell, vscode-extensions

When I open a Haskell file in VS Code (with the Haskell extension installed) I always get the following notification:

[image]

<sup>transcription of image: "*Need to download hls-1.9.1.0, continue?*"</sup>

How can I switch this check off? Has the Haskell extension some hidden setting not to check for and  upgrade anything over the internet?

(Or if this is not possible, can I somehow tell GHC and GHCup when they are asked to upgrade, then not to do anything?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the setting you are looking for is `haskell.upgradeGHCup` (boolean).

Its description says:

> Whether to upgrade GHCup automatically when 'manageHLS' is set to 'GHCup'.

([source: extension's package.json file](https://github.com/haskell/vscode-haskell/blob/master/package.json))